# Spring MVC - Hibernate form:errors and bindingresult, jsp don't display error messages

Tags: hibernate, validation, jsp, spring-mvc

I use Spring MVC 3, Spring 3 and Hibernate 2.5 . 
I want to validate my inputs but i can't make it work : nothing appear on the page.

My jsp

```
<form:form commandName="entrepriseSearch" action="/search" modelAttribute="entrepriseSearch" class="search" method="POST">
    <table class="search">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="champ1"/>
                    <form:errors path="champ1"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
                        ... 
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

My Controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "search", method = { POST })
public String search(@Valid @ModelAttribute("entrepriseSearch")  EntrepriseSearch entrepriseSearch, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        // bindingResult works 
        return "domain/domentreprise/showSearchForm";
    }

    return "/search";
}
```

My Bean

```
public class EntrepriseSearch extends SearchForm implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String champ1;

@MinMaxLength(min = 9,max=14, nullable = true)
public String getChamp1() {
    return champ1;
}

public void setChamp1(String champ1) {
    this.champ1= champ1;
} }
```

What am i missing ? 
The binding works but the errors message are not displayed. 
Thanks

Comment: You may want to try to print out the results of `bindingResult.getFieldErrors()` for debugging purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to add a message to report when the error happens:

```
@MinMaxLength(min = 9,max=14, nullable = true, message="Error here")
public String getChamp1() {
    return champ1;
}
```

P/s: You may want to try to print out the results of `bindingResult.getFieldErrors()` for debugging purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Check , during debug , which message code has the field error. Than make sure that you have specified  message source that can serve messages for error codes.

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource" p:basenames="message ...
```